# Java regex groups with .* vs normal regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to use regex to grab 2 pieces of one full string. I've got the regex working fine on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Here is a sample string:

```
Regex is fun when it works 99
```

Here is my Regex

`(.*)\\s+(\\d+)$`

These are groups I get when using Java's matcher (matches()) and pattern:

```
1: Regex is fun when it works 99
2: Regex is fun when it works
```

Using normal regex (on RegExr), I get the results I actually expect:

```
1: Regex is fun when it works
2: 99
```

Are there any caveats when putting Regex into Java that I need to be aware of? I already have \\ for special characters. Maybe there is a trick to using . ?

If you want a sample app to copy and paste:

```
String str = "Regex is fun when it works 33";
String regx = "(.*)\\s+(\\d+)$"

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regx);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.matches()) {
   for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + m.group(i));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not getting the `99` you expect is that the whole match `group(0)` is not counted in `groupcount()`, so the `for` loop is bailing out too early.

Therefore, if you change `i < m.groupCount()` to `i <= m.groupCount()` you will get

> 0: Regex is fun when it works 99
>   1: Regex is fun when it works
>   2: 99

Comment: Hi Mike,

Ah, it was hiding there all along. I feel like an idiot! Must be getting rusty.

Thank you for pointing out the fix :)

Answer (score 3):

Change your first capture to be non greedy, as follows:

```
(.*?)\\s+(\\d+)$
```

Refer to "Watch out for Greedyness" in [this regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), but put simply, the trailing `?` makes the preceeding `*` quantifier *lazy*.  That is, it will stop consuming characters as early as possible.

Comment: Hey Sepster,

Thanks for the quick answer and the more efficient Regex! 
This lazy Regex better fits what I am looking to capture. It also seems like it'd have better performance, but that's just an assumption :)

Combining this with MikeM's answer, I've fixed the problem!

Thank you!